# How to integrate WooComerceAPI into React?

Tags: woocommerce

I wanted to receive data to my site on React through the API.I did everything as stated in the documentation, performed the installation of `npm install --save woocommerce-api`, created the object with parameters as in the documentation http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#pagination

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import WooCommerceAPI from 'woocommerce-api';


class Goods extends Component {
    WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
    url: 'http://portland.com/wp/', // Your store URL
    consumerKey: '**KEY**', // Your consumer key
    consumerSecret: '**KEY**', // Your consumer secret
    wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
    version: 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
  });
    render() {
        return(
        <div className="GoodsMain">
            <div className="Goods">
            <img src="/images/photo.png" alt="appletv"/><br/>
            <div className="TextAlign">
            <span className="NameOfGood">{WooCommerce.get('products/1').name}</span><br/>
            <span className="StyleOfGood">black</span><br/>
            <span className="PriceOfGood">$49.99</span>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Goods;
```

But I get `Line 20: 'WooCommerce' is not defined no-undef`
Can u help me integrate correctly API in my site?

Comment: In your render function, you need `this.WooCommerce`. This isn't about React or WooCommerce, or integrating an API, this is just about how classes work.

Comment: From what i understood while going through woocommerce docs, woocommerce-api is for nodejs(server side) and not for reactjs

Comment: About the general issue: React is front-end, the WooCommerce API is backend. What you need to do is use the API in node.js or PHP or Ruby. Then in your React app, you make requests to your own backend (which grabs wordpress data using the WooCommerce API and forwards it to your React client).

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand what I should do.I use WordPress as a backend for my site and want receive data from API.I must create node.js file with 'var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');

var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://example.com', // Your store URL
  consumerKey: 'consumer_key', // Your consumer key
  consumerSecret: 'consumer_secret', // Your consumer secret
  wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
  version: 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce WP REST API version' and this file take data from woocomerce?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you have to use the oauth authentication for getting the data from the woo-commerce rest api because your wordpress is on the server where there is no ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1). Use axios library (https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/) to call the WooCommerce Rest API.

2). To simplify the authentication process, make sure you enable SSL on your Wordpress hosting (I tried authenticate on the non SSL, it appears the process was not that easy, compared the SSL one).

3). Follow the steps from this link to generate the WooCommerce Rest API key 
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#authentication

4). Once everything setup, test retrieve list of products using Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/).

```
[GET]
https://{{host}}/{{wordpressFolder}}/wp-json/wc/v2/products/

[HEADER] 
// Inside your React code, do this:
const basicToken = btoa(PRODUCTS_CONSUMER_KEY+':'+PRODUCTS_CONSUMER_SECRET)

Authorization: Basic ${basicToken}
```