# How to make React accept WooCommerceAPI?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, woocommerce

I make my site on React.js but back-end i wanna use WordPress(WooCommerce).
After I read about WooCommerce integration in React, I realized that the data needs to be passed through the API.
From my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378184/how-to-integrate-woocomerceapi-into-react), I realized that you can not connect the npm install -save woocommerce-api package to React as it is a Back-end package.For me, it remains unclear how then I can connect React and WooCommerce. You can show what kind of example or in steps write what you need to do. There is very little information about this on the Internet.